# What does the `[4,5) notation mean when compile facebook sdk in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks, the syntax to add the facebook sdk is as the following:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'
```

How does `[4, 5)` work? I have not seen this syntax anywhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a ivy syntax.
`[4, 5)` means `4 <= x < 5`.